# Can you run Sagemaker Python SDK on Windows?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

The [documentation](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk) says that sagemaker-python-sdk is only supported by Unix/Mac OS.

Is there a possibility to run sagemaker python libraries in Python.

I actually installed sagemaker-scikit-learn-extension on my windows Python environment however there is an error due to the library mlio missing(I installed it).

I assume this is due to me running Windows, but I don't know. Does anybody have any ideas if this libraries are runnable on Windows?

Comment: We are facing the same issue with mlio although we have install it in Linux. Did you find any fix for it?

Comment: I was using windows, I got it working on linux virtual machine.